# How to install Davicom 9102 ethernet driver on 64-bit windows?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit

I have a very old ethernet card that only works on 32-bit windows, but I want to install it on 64-bit because my computer RAM is limited to 2gb. It cannot use all 4gb (the all amount of RAM). Because my computer supports 64-bit but the ethernet card driver doesn't. I have tried PatchPAE2 and I have also tried Ubuntu and other linux versions but none of them had supported the Davicom 9102 driver.

I am wondering if there is any the Davicom 9102 driver on 64-bit windows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your computer is hard limited to 2GB then 64-bit is going to be largely useless. You'd be better off installing a 32-bit OS and having done with. Especially if your hardware is not compatible with 64-bit either.

Comment: It seems that Davicom 9102 is a pretty basic PCI to Fast Ethernet adapter. Is there any reason you need this specific model, instead of another card which would likely be supported by default in Win7? They go for less than $10.

Comment: @Mokubai: I think the post meant "my computer _would be_ limited to 2 GB".